# Trying to get two values on the one table but result to none

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the two values on one table but keeps saying no result eventhough theres a data on it

here is the sql that i try
 `SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE Column 1 = Value 1 AND Column 2 = Value 2;`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We need a bit more information to help you. Some sample data and your desired result set would be very useful. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: note: i trying to get the two values on one table using AND condition

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear. I guess you want rows from your table where either filter condition matches.  Try this.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE (Column 1 = Value 1 OR Column 2 = Value 2);
```

It takes a while to get fluent with WHERE logic. Don't give up!

**Pro tip** Always wrap your `OR` conditions in `(`parentheses`)`. `AND`s and `OR`s are evaluated left to right with equal operator precedence, so if you don't use those parentheses you'll have hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: i meant to get two conditions on the one table

Answer (score 0):

Use the OR operator instead of AND to get the results where one (or both) of the WHERE-clauses is (are) matching.